# Eliminar espacio en blanco PHP

Tags: php, lua

Mediante php genero y guardo un archivo txt que contien los datos captados de un textfield, pero al leerlo desde una aplicacion que estoy creando resulta que tiene un espacio en blanco de mas. 
**¿Como puedo hacer para guardar mi txt con la lineas de info que yo desee sin generar un espacio en blanco al final?**

Codigo PHP para guardar datos en TXT:

```
if ($_POST["txtopc1"]) 
    {
        $miopc1=$_POST["txtopc1"];
        if ($miopc1!="")
        { 
                $archivo='D:\letritastv\aplicacion\nivel_1\opcion1.txt';
                $file = fopen($archivo, 'a') or die (); 
                fwrite($file,$miopc1.PHP_EOL);
                fclose($file);
                echo "He recibido en el archivo.php: ".$_POST["txtopc1"];
        }
        else { $miopc1=""; }
    }
        else{echo "He recibido un campo vacio";}
```

Codigo para leer mi archivo en LUA:

```
 local opc1 = io.open("nivel_1/opcion1.txt","r")
 local mopc1= opc1:read("*all")
 objdib = objetos:new()
 objdib:dibujar(mopc1)


 function objetos:dibujar (mopc1)
    canvas:attrColor('red')
    canvas:attrFont('Tiresias','40','normal')
    canvas:drawText(70,100,mopc1)
    canvas:flush()
 end
```

El resultado al leer mi archivo txt es un cuadro que representa un espacio en blanco:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es bien sencillo si entiendo bien tu pregunta.

Tu tienes un `<form>` el cual envía información a PHP y la recibes en esta línea:

`$miopc1=$_POST["txtopc1"];`

Dentro de esta línea hay 2 errores, no limpias la información (pero si para ti no es relevante entonces ignorar esto) y el segundo no compruebas que haya información (de igual forma, ignorar si no es relevante).

Pero a su vez quieres remover los espacios en blanco estando entonces algo como:

`frase[ ]` (Entiéndase el [ ] como el espacio en blanco).

Para esto, hay una función en PHP la cual te permite remover esos enormes espacios en blanco que pudieran haber:

La función [trim()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) en PHP (link a la documentación) te permite remover esos espacios en blanco pasando como argumento el texto quedando entonces tu línea de la siguiente forma:

`$miopc1=trim($_POST["txtopc1"]);`

Y con esto quedaría listo.

Comment: He puesto lo que me ha indicado pero me sigue generando el mismo error, me he dado cuenta que es por el .PHP_EOL que añado pero sin el no puedo hacer un salto de linea y este es el que me crea el espacio en blanco, como hacer para guardar una nueva linea sin que esto suceda???

Comment: al realizar el trim no se da un salto de linea, escribe todo seguido en txt

Comment: ¿txtopc1 es un textarea?.

Answer (score 1):

El problema creo que está en el fopen, ya que por cada salto de linea presenta problemas con \n, leyendo la documentación dice lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo cual entonces en tu opción de lectura fopen seria algo como

```
$file = fopen($archivo, 'ab') or die (); 
 //acompañar el modo de escritura con el flag b
```

Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php

Comment: He añadido a mi linea de codigo $file = fopen($archivo, 'ab') or die ();  pero no ha dado resultado me sigue generando el espacio en blanco al final de cada linea de mi txt.

Comment: Ummm,  entonces creo que será mejor remover el espacio final después de leer el archivo con substring

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar de esta manera saludes.

```
if ($_POST["txtopc1"]) 
    {
        $miopc1=$_POST["txtopc1"];
        if ($miopc1!="")
        { 
                $archivo='D:\letritastv\aplicacion\nivel_1\opcion1.txt';
                $file = fopen($archivo, 'a') or die (); 
                fwrite($file,PHP_EOL .$miopc1);
                fclose($file);
                echo "He recibido en el archivo.php: ".$_POST["txtopc1"];
        }
        else { $miopc1=""; }
    }
        else{echo "He recibido un campo vacio";}
```